# Ampscript in marketing cloud - If value LIKE

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

Similar to SQL, I was wondering if your able to add ampscript that say if a value is like a wildcard. For example,  %%[IF Value LIKE "%1234" THEN]%%

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [indexOf](https://ampscript.guide/indexof) function:

```ampscript
%%[ if indexof(AttributeValue("value"),"1234") > 0 then ]%%
```

If it needs to be more specific you can use a combination of the [length](https://ampscript.guide/length/) and [subString](https://ampscript.guide/substring/) functions.

Comment: This worked thank you!